# Working with Combinations/Probability in Excel

Tags: excel

Working an a project with many more possible combinations and I'm not sure how to approach it, so I'm going to ask how to do it on a smaller scale and then apply it to a larger scale.
I have to buy 1 of product A and 1 of product B
They both come in 100 varieties at different prices.

For product A:
TABLE 1 (A1:B6)

Dollars-Versions

1-15

2-20

3-30

4-20

5-15

and Product B
TABLE 2 (C1:D6)

Dollars-Versions

1-40

2-30

3-20

4-5

5-5

I know the minimum I can spend is $2 (600 combinations) & the Max is $10 (75 combinations), and there are 10000 (100x100) total combinations

If I put the dollar values 2-10 in cells E2:E10, is there a formula to quickly determine the number of combinations for each net dollar value in cells F2:f10?

I imagine it would have to be done with an sumif array formula, but I can't start to figure out what it would be. If I had a small data set like this, I would make a crosstab, but my data set is too large to do it efficiently.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your mean 15 X 40 = 600 combinations for $2, right?

Comment: yeah that's what I meant. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a formula like this:-

```
=SUM((A$2:A$6+TRANSPOSE(C$2:C$6)=F2)*B$2:B$6*TRANSPOSE(D$2:D$6))
```

which would have to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

It builds up a 2D array with ones at the elements where the corresponding cells in the two lists add up to the amount you have to spend, then multiplies it by the corresponding numbers of combinations.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tom!
This works perfect.
Now we'll see how well it works with the large data set.

Comment: 2.2*10^12 combinations and going strong.
Thank you again!

Comment: Wow! That is impressive.